# logical 'and' in matching branches

Tags: rust

How to express logical 'and' in `match`' arms ?

Like the following:

```rust
fn main() {
    let expr: Result<_, ()> = Ok(String::from("hello"));
    let _res = match expr {
        Ok(s) && s.trim() != "" => s,
        _ => String::from("None"),
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [match](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/flow_control/match/guard.html) [guard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#extra-conditionals-with-match-guards):

```rust
fn main() {
    let expr: Result<_, ()> = Ok(String::from("hello"));
    let _res = match expr {
        Ok(s) if s.trim() != "" => s,
        _ => String::from("None"),
    };
}
```

Comment: Is String::from somehow better than `.to_string()` or `.to_owned()` ? And is it possible to use the product of `s.trim()` in the condition as the return value? without double invoking in case of supposed `s.trim()` for the `Ok(s) if s.trim() != ""` arm?

Comment: "And is it possible to use the product of s.trim() in the condition as the return value?" no match guard are very limited that why I never use them